# Implode/explode table data to array in PHP query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not that good at PHP and i am stuck right now.

I have this code in one of my table rows in my db. `Danish_English_Swedish`. The data is from the table teacher.

I have this Query: `$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE subject = ? ORDER BY id DESC");`

I have created an AJAX request which is called when a `<select>` is changed. This request is sent to a page that contains the above query. This select contains options as danish, english and swedish.

example:

If i select `Danish` in the `<select>` and a teacher has a row containing `Danish_English_Swedish` i want to grab the `Danish` from the data so it mathes the users request.

Maybe you can implode/explode and make it to an array and check it that way?

Any solutions are welcome!

Comment: If you're encoding multiple values into a single column that's probably a violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Underscore-separated is really an irregular format as well.

Comment: Those should be separate columns in the database.

Comment: I agree you should normalize your database. Always. Do it now. As for your question, you could use `FIND_IN_SET('Danish',REPLACE('_',',','Danish_English_Swedish'))` in the `WHERE` part of your select.

Answer (score 1):

You need [LIKE statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE column LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC");
```

NOTE 1: change `column` name to the name of column where `Danish_English_Swedish` is contained

NOTE 2: check collation of your database/table if it is _ci (case-insensitive), otherwise you'd like to do [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) before running query and also store values in lower case in table

NOTE 3: from the description you provided I have feeling, that your database structure and table columns are not well-optimized for working with them at all, but for your particular case answer is above.

Comment: Thanks! All i needed

Comment: Plus one for note 3!!